# JUnit Testing with Google App Engine dev server

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm new to GAE and trying to setup a few JUnit tests. In this example provided by Google:

```
public class LocalDatastoreTest {

private final LocalServiceTestHelper helper =
    new LocalServiceTestHelper(new LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig());

@Before
public void setUp() {
    helper.setUp();
}

@After
public void tearDown() {
    helper.tearDown();
}

// run this test twice to prove we're not leaking any state across tests
private void doTest() {
    DatastoreService ds = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
    assertEquals(0, ds.prepare(new Query("yam")).countEntities(withLimit(10)));
    ds.put(new Entity("yam"));
    ds.put(new Entity("yam"));
    assertEquals(2, ds.prepare(new Query("yam")).countEntities(withLimit(10)));
}

@Test
public void testInsert1() {
    doTest();
}

@Test
public void testInsert2() {
    doTest();
}
```

}

the following line is used to add an Entity to the local datastore:

```
ds.put(new Entity("yam"));
```

That works just fine for me. However, I'm using JDO and want to persist one my own POJOs (e.g. Cars) but Cars is not of type Entity, which is what this method requires. Is there a different method or service I can use to accomplish this?

Comment: Can your POJO just extend Entity?

Comment: @citizen com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity is marked Final.

Answer (score 2):

maybe you could use objectify-appengine..  for example

```
package com.intranet.entity;
import com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Entity;
import com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Id;
import com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Index;

@Entity
public class Voto { 
@Id Long id;
@Index String email;
@Index String actividad;

public Voto(){}
public Voto(String email, String actividad) {
    this.email = email;
    this.actividad = actividad;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}
public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}
public String getActividad() {
    return actividad;
}
public void setActividad(String actividad) {
    this.actividad = actividad;
}   
}
```

TEST

```
public class VotoTest {

private final static LocalServiceTestHelper helper = new LocalServiceTestHelper(
            new LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig());

@Before
public void setUp() {
        helper.setUp();
}

@After
public void tearDown() {
        helper.tearDown();
}

@Test
public void testEmbedded(){
         DatastoreService ds = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
         Voto voto1 = new Voto("test@localhost","actividad1");
         ofy().save().entity(voto1).now(); 
         assertEquals(1, ds.prepare(new Query("Voto")).countEntities(withLimit(10)));             

 } 
 }
```

It works perfectly